# How to select specific ID within a draggable element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML here:

```
<div class="dev draggableDevelopers" id="devCard<?= ++$index ?>">
    <p class="card-text" id="devCardText<?= $index ?>">
        <span id="devCardName"><?= $user->getUsername() ?></span>
        <button class="trashButton" id="trash<?= $index ?>" onclick="removeDeveloperFromSupport(<?= $index ?>)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>trash</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

This is a draggable and droppable elements are defined by this jQuery:

```
$('.draggableDevelopers').draggable( {
    containment: 'document',
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: true,
    stack: '.card'
} );

$('.droppableRotaSlot').droppable( {
        accept: '.draggableDevelopers',
        hoverClass: 'hovered',
        drop: handleDeveloperRotaDrop
    } );
```

The drop event is defined by:

```
function handleDeveloperRotaDrop(event, ui) {
ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
}
```

What I wish to do is get the content of `id="devCardName"` upon the element being dropped. Is this possible, if so how? I am new to jQuery so I apologise if this has been asked before but I couldn't quite word it into a proper question to find a duplicate.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include your droppable code since.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I've edited the code to include the drop event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the draggable element when it's dropped via the second parameter that is automatically passed to your `drop` callback.

```
$('.droppableRotaSlot').droppable( {
    accept: '.draggableDevelopers',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleDeveloperRotaDrop
});

function handleDeveloperRotaDrop(evt, ui) {
    //ui.draggable stores a reference to the draggable
    //additionally, ui.helper stores a reference to the 'helper' representing
    //the draggable during the drag
}
```

Comment: But how do I access the text contents of #devCardName?

Comment: Well, let's think about it. I told you that `ui.draggable` is a reference to the **draggable** element. That is the element with class `draggableDevelopers`. So it's then a question of knowing how to navigate from there to its inner element with ID `devCardName`. How would you select a child/descendant element from a container element?